# Why the code produce ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Observable.Using(() => new EventLoopScheduler(), els => Observable
            .Defer(() => Observable.Return(1))
            .SubscribeOn(els))
        .Subscribe();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Why the code above will produce a ObjectDisposedException? How exactly SubscribeOn works?

---

More details:

```
//can't compile
class DataService : ObservableBase<Unit>
{
    protected override IDisposable SubscribeCore(IObserver<Unit> o) 
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() => _httpClient.Get(...)))
            .RepeatWithDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .ObserveOn(SchedulerEx.Current)//observe back to event loop
            .Do(...)
            .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
            .Subscribe(o)
    }
}
class Controller 
{
    void Start()
    {
        _instance = Observable.Using(
            () => SchedulerEx.Create(), 
            els => _dataService.SubscribeOn(els));
    }
    void Stop()
    {
        _instance.Dispose();
    }
}
class SchedulerEx 
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static EventLoopScheduler Current;
    public EventLoopScheduler Create() 
    {
        var els = new EventLoopScheduler();
        els.Schedule(() => SchedulerEx.Current = els);
        return els;
    } 
}
static void Main() 
{
    var controller = kernel.Get<Controller>();
    controller.Start();
    controller.Stop();//throw if stop immediately
}
```

What I want to implement: in the windows service application, I have multiple DataService independently running on their own event loop, and I can observe back to the current event loop anywhere.

Comment: Why are you trying to put the `EventLoopScheduler` in the query? It seems to defeat the purpose of using this scheduler.

Comment: I`m trying to start a polling service which suppose to run on a EventLoopScheduler and when service is cancelled, thread should end too.

Comment: Why is it supposed to run on an `EventLoopScheduler`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's quite the pretzel:

- `Observable.Using` is like the C# `using` statement: It disposes an `IDisposable` after the observable has concluded.
- `Observable.Defer` delays running the included code until a subscriber subscribes.
- `SubscribeOn` dictates which thread the observable should be subscribed on based on the passed in `IScheduler`.

I tested the following, which also bombs out:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Observable.Using(() => new EventLoopScheduler(), els => 
        Observable.Empty<int>()
            .SubscribeOn(els)
    )
        .Subscribe();
}
```

... so `Defer` has no impact.

Clearly `Using` is disposing the scheduler before it's being used. If you change `Observable.Empty` (or `Observable.Return`) to something that doesn't complete immediately (like `Observable.Never` or `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Take(2)`, then it won't bomb out.

It looks like a race condition bug in `EventLoopScheduler`: Probably both the `Observable.Using` and `EventLoopScheduler` are trying to call `Dispose`, and if the wrong one gets there first, blow up.

I would recommend dropping the `Using`.

Comment: Replace Using with Finally cause the same result.

Comment: But I'm kind of understand why this happening.Just like someone saw off the branch his  sitting on.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
var els = new EventLoopScheduler();
var subscription =
    Observable
        .Return(1)
        .Finally(() => els.Schedule(() => els.Dispose()))
        .ObserveOn(els)
        .Subscribe();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.Using(() => new EventLoopScheduler(), 
            els => new AnonymousObservable<long>(o => els.Schedule(Unit.Default, (_, s) => source.Subscribe(o))));
```

Finally I resolve the problem by the code above.

Comment: No, please don't use this code. There is far simpler ways for you to do this.

Comment: Try this: `Observable.Using(() => new EventLoopScheduler(), els => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Never<int>().StartWith(1)).SubscribeOn(els)).Subscribe();`. It's almost exactly your original code.

Comment: The posted code is a minimal bug reproduce example, so actually there is a big service in Defer.

Comment: What do you mean by "a big service in Defer."?

Comment: I'm writing a windows services. A big service means the whole application's entry point is in the Defer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Perhaps you should have put that in your question?

Comment: Well, I perferred not to ask someone to solve my problem, but tell me how rx.net works so I can solve it by self

Comment: You should try to explain your issue as this question is too abstract and it's hard to understand why you need to do what you're doing. Can you try to explain your problem then I'll have a better chance of understanding the overall context?

Comment: I added a more detail example to explain what I'm trying to implement, thank u

Comment: That code is a mess of things that seem to relate to each other but don't quite line up. Right now your entire question is an X-Y problem. You think you have a solution Y to your problem X so you've asked about Y. Surely you can ask about X? What you want to do?

Comment: What I want to do is trying to (1)Run multiple complex Observable on each independent EventLoopScheduler. (2)ObserveOn back to corrent EventLoopScheduler when I need.(3)Cancel the Observable at any time without Exception.(4)When Observable is disposed, EventLoopScheduler get disposed too, thread should be shutdown gracefully

Comment: No, I mean what are you **really** trying to do? Forget about `EventLoopScheduler`. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Based on DI and Rx.Net, trying to find an appropriate thread model solution to construct a multi-thread windows service app?

Comment: But why? You're not getting to the crux of what you're trying to do. Forget threads and DI and Rx.Net. What are you trying to do? i.e. I'm connecting to multiple external sources that each need to receive data in real-time such that no service blocks any other.

Comment: Got what you mean. One service is polling data from database and upload changes by http. Another one is receiving remote procedure call then communicate with hardware device by serial port.Both of them should work in real time and no block.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure because of `.Using()`. Internally it (most probably) proceeds on `using () {}` construction, which calls `.Dispose()` at the end of itself implicitly.

Comment: Observable.Using supposed to dispose the EventLoopScheduler after the Defer/Return Observable disposed, right?

Comment: Might be the case. At least, native C#'s `using ()` would do exactly so. I haven't decompiled source code, but the functions name pretty much dictates it's behavior...

Comment: The source code is right here: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/Using.cs. There's no `using` statement, because observables can outlive their scope.

Comment: @Shlomo indeed. Hence, my assumption is erroneous. Hovever, I am not quite convinced: makes sense to go through the code; it might not contain using statement and yet behave in exactly the same fashion.